# Guidelines for LBS Mobile application development

Tags: mobile, geolocation, gps, gis

i need some help!, i am planning to develop such LBS Mobile Application which find nearest things based on gps data from mobile.

1.what are the best free and (preferably) open source technologies for development?.
2.What programming language to use for development of such application?.
3.what are the points to be considered?

I need the general overview of the requirements for planning, I was interested in having a general understanding of the data, tools, and frameworks required to accomplish the job.

Comment: Do you mean mobile phones? Which mobile phones (iPhone, Android, Symbian, Windows Mobile...)?

Answer (score 1):

The future proof way to write your application is using Web technologies.

Iphone and Android devices already support the [W3C Geolocation API](http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/), with more on the way.

I recommend you take a look at a sample http://geo.webvm.net/ to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

On Symbian phones, you can access location information via C++, java (when [JSR-256](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=256) is implemented) and probably python.

You might also want to look into the Qt runtime as that is the new technology to use for Symbian development.

To start with Symbian application development, start with the [Fundation's developer wiki](http://developer.symbian.org)

Both [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950172/jsr-256-battery-events) and [Forum Nokia](http://library.forum.nokia.com/topic/Java_Developers_Library/GUID-83AFD884-2419-4CAF-B386-71CE8387BE64.html) contain information about how to use JSR-256.

Relevant plug: There is whole chapter on LBS in [Quick Recipes on Symbian OS](http://developer.symbian.org/wiki/index.php/Symbian_Press_Books_A_to_Z_by_Author).