# are there any good references for J2ME accelerometer, I don't seem to find any

Tags: mobile, java-me, accelerometer, sensors

I googled that but couldn't find any sufficient resources/ samples/ tutorials, 
any help appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any phone that has a working standard accelerometer implementation for J2ME but if one exists (and I would start by looking at the very latest Nokia Series40 phones), it should use JSR-256.

You can find code on how to use the JSR at this other stackoverflow question:

[JSR 256 battery events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950172/jsr-256-battery-events/)